# JSON "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray is not marked as serializable

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I converting `DataTable` into JSON file.

I am using JSON.NETv3.5 and with folowing code

```
 string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds);
```

I am having following error while debugging.

`Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' in Assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json.Net20, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' is not marked as serializable.`

What should I do?

Comment: it's seem working fine with JSON.NETv3.5, not getting why error occur with you?

Comment: I have the same doubt, and alternative that you can suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try with below code and let me know its work for you or not. For more detail please refer this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/624888/Converting-DataTable-to-JSON-Format-in-Csharp-and)

```
 public string GetJson(DataTable dt)
        {
            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new

            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows =
              new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> row = null;

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName.Trim(), dr[col]);
                }
                rows.Add(row);
            }
            return serializer.Serialize(rows);
        }
```

Comment: Let me check will get back to you

Comment: The problem is solved. There was problem in the declaration from my side.

Comment: Can you guide me how can I use the JSON into dotnethighchart?

Comment: SPandya You should elaborate your own solution for others' benefit.